# Passing a timestamp header onto upstream servers with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'd like to have my Nginx load balancer send a timestamp in a header onto the upstream servers.

I tried something like this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Start-Time $msec;
```

Of course, $msec is a log variable and Nginx gives an error:

```
Restarting nginx: [emerg]: unknown "msec" variable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$msec` is indeed a variable that lives only during log writing.

The easiest solution would be to build Nginx with Perl module and define a variable backed by Perl subroutine:

```
# at 'http' context
perl_set $unix_timestamp 'sub {
  time();
}';

# where you want it:
proxy_set_header X-Start-Time $unix_timestamp;
```

Answer (score 1):

$time_iso8601 is both machine- & human-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

With [ngx_http_ssi_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) it's possible to use the embedded Variable `$date_gmt`. So

```
proxy_set_header X-Start-Time $date_gmt;
```